# In angular JS, how to execute a line of JQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In the view I have this:

```
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="resultsTable">
        <thead>
          <th>Classification</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
          <td>{{result.result}}</td>
          <td>{{result.date}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

I want to use floating header, but as the table is empty when page is first loaded, it gives me weird results (http://www.fixedheadertable.com/)

If table content was static, this would work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#resultsTable').fixedHeaderTable({ footer: true, cloneHeadToFoot: false, fixedColumn: false   });
});
```

In controller I have this function which loads data after pressing a button:

```
 $scope.loadResults = function() {
    var url = "URL WITH QUERY";
    $http.get(url).success(
      function(data, status, headers, config) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.results.push({date: data[i].date, p: data[i].p, result: data[i].result});
        }

//**IDEALLY I WOULD WANT TO RUN THE JQUERY LINE HERE**

      }
    );
  };
```

So what I want to do is to run this line that I would normally run on document ready, after loading all data into the **results** array.

How would you do it?

Please, please, supply an example as I keep reading about "directives" but nobody says how exactly it allows calling jquery, where wanted line of jquery should be put or how it can be called from my controller.

Comment: your comment for the jquery location is incorrect. needs to be inside the function

Comment: @galchen Does AngularJS guarantee DOM manipulation from model changes synchronously?

Comment: @galchen fixed. @ user it's incorrect but I want to show what I want to achieve

Comment: I think you can use events to solve this. I'm not sure if DOM manipulation is synchronous, but i'd assume that using $emit after updating the $scope.results array would do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve this using scope events `$emit` or `$broadcast` and `$on` in your scope to call jQuery functions at appropriate time.

Difference between `$emit` and `$broadcast` :

- $broadcast -- dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes,
- $emit -- dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy.

This example will help to understand it : http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/GkarV/

Comment: This example is other way round. I see an event being emitted and picked up by controller. I want an event emitted from controller and picked up by something else that will run jquery

Comment: If you want to pick-up that event out of the `$scope`, then you can use `$rootScope`.

Comment: Also, I see one more option in this case. You can use `$q.when(value)` to hold the function call until the `value` is not resolved.
-- [$q.when](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q#when)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from doing this:

```
$scope.loadResults = function() {
    var url = "URL WITH QUERY";
    $http.get(url).success(
      function(data, status, headers, config) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.results.push({date: data[i].date, p: data[i].p, result: data[i].result});
        }
        $('#resultsTable').fixedHeaderTable({ footer: true, cloneHeadToFoot: false, fixedColumn: false   });
      }
    );
  };
```

but it is not considered best practice.

Additionally, you may need to wait for the Angular digest cycle to complete so that the ng-repeat has been processed.  You can do that using either `$timeout()` or possibly a `$scope.$evalAsync()` (I am not 100% sure on the later working in this case, it may still fire too early so you would need to test it).

A cleaner solution would be to create a directive for that plugin.  I don't see anything in the docs for the *Fixed Header Table* plugin to allow for dynamic data, so you would need to resolve that issue with either promises to ensure initialization happens after the data is ready and rendered, or a watch on the results array in order to call `destroy` on the plugin and re-initialize it.